# how do I make a resizable scrolling text box in a fluid layout?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, fluid-layout

I've tried using Dreamweaver's standard fluid layout, and modified it with 10% column widths and 24 columns on the desktop design.  I've tried creating a div within a div (bear with me, I'm a noob at Dreamweaver), and set the constraints of the text box to be within the outside div, and haven't been able to come up with a solution on that front.

I tried to set the parameters of the text box itself but that doesn't work either because of the conflict of % v. px.  In the fluid layout, I'm using % for the resizing to work.

In essence, the issue lies within being able to set the vertical constraints on the text box to be in proportion for when the screen size changes; horizontal is fine because I can just set the width constraint in Dreamweaver's design module.

I'm thinking that I'll have to set it up through a javascript of some sort; although I know nothing about java except to pluck code from someone who's built it and plug it into the site.

Sorry for the rambling nature of this post, and I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was helping you in your other question regarding jQuery and I decided to snoop around and found this question. I understand you want a fluid height for a text box in a column. That can be achieved like this:

CSS:

```
/* 
   In order to use width/height: 100% on the body and html
   You need to remove the margins and padding on them, otherwise
   you'll see a vertical and horizontal scroll bar, which is awful.
   This way, it removed margins and paddings on everything, ultimately
   leading to better styling overall. 
*/

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Create a wrapper to base all other %-based measurements off of. */
#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* The column that the textbox will be inside */
#someColumn
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#someColumn textarea
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    /* The textbox will now be 50% the height of #someColumn */
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="someColumn">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Here's a jsFiddle to see what it looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/Ntf49/)